# access data of struts2 nested iterator in action

Tags: struts2, iterator

```
<s:iterator var="parent" value="studentList">
   <s:iterator var="child1" value="#parent.subjectList">
       <s:property value="%{subjectName}" />: 
       <s:textfield id="subject" name="%parent.subject.id}" theme="simple" />
   </s:iterator>   
</s:iterator>
```

I have a jsp page with the above code. I have two lists i) studentList, ii) subjectList.
For each student there is a subjectList. Now I have to save the marks. How can I get these values in my action ? I am using Struts2. 
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Where is the mark feild. how do u wanted in action class.? As hash map key as subject then value as edited /added marks?..provide in clearly.

Answer (score 0):

This is how the JSP code will look like:

```
    <s:form action="saveaction" >
        <s:iterator value="lstBean" id="lstBean" status="outerStat">
            <s:textfield value="%{name}" name="lstBean[%{#outerStat.index}].name"/>
            <s:textfield value="%{amt}" name="lstBean[%{#outerStat.index}].amt"/>
            <s:textfield value="%{id}" name="lstBean[%{#outerStat.index}].id"/>
            <s:iterator value="%{lstString}" status="myStat">
                <s:textfield name="lstBean[%{#outerStat.index}].lstString[%{#myStat.index}]"/>
            </s:iterator>
        </s:iterator>
        <s:submit value="Click me to submit lstBean"/>
    </s:form>
```

Following is the bean(XBean) whose List is used in the JSP:

```
public class XBean
{    
private ArrayList<String> lstString=new ArrayList<String>();
private String name;
private Double amt;
private Integer id;
//Getters and setters of fields
}
```

Now you can simply have a field lstBean with setters in your submitting action (saveaction) and hey you are done.